# Does ArrayAccess extend Traversable?

Tags: php

Does [ArrayAccess](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/class.arrayaccess.php) extend [Traversable](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/class.traversable.php)? The man pages for each make no mention of the other. The [ArrayAccess](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/class.arrayaccess.php) page does not indicate that it extends Traversable, but it doesn't explicitly deny it either. I ask because I have code that could take either Traversable or ArrayAccess, and I want to make sure that I need to test for both.

Comment: Definition of `ArrayAccess` is __pretty obvious__, isn't it?

Comment: And the man page for Traversable says, from the beginning: "Interface to detect if a class is traversable using foreach." Yet you can traverse ArrayAccess objects with foreach too.

Comment: I don't think you can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer No.

for what you need you can use `arrayiterator` http://php.net/manual/en/class.arrayiterator.php

---

- Interfaces do not implement each other "it **extends**."
- Interfaces are made to **implemented** or **extended** by **developer** through **interface / abstract classes / classes**.

> interfaces are contracts that some code implements and adheres to and
>   other code depends upon. It allows us to have assurance that any given
>   dependency will implement the methods we expect. Even further, with
>   the upcoming PHP 7, we can also use type hints (object and scalars)
>   and return types to further ensure that concrete implementations
>   adhere to the contracts.